# How to change roll-out percentage of release track using Fastlane supply

Tags: android, google-play, fastlane

I'm trying to increase the staged roll-out percentage of an existing Google Play Store release using Fastlane's `supply` (`upload_to_play_store`) action (https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/supply/).

However, executing `fastlane supply --track rollout --rollout 0.50` does NOT bump up the roll-out percentage to 50%, instead it does not change anything in the Google Play Developer Console, even though fastlane shows a success message.

Fastlane's output:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
|               Summary for supply 2.122.0                |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
| track                   | production                    |
| rollout                 | 0.5                           |
| package_name            | com.mydomain.myapp            |
| metadata_path           | ./fastlane/metadata/android   |
| json_key_data           | ********                      |
| skip_upload_apk         | false                         |
| skip_upload_aab         | false                         |
| skip_upload_metadata    | false                         |
| skip_upload_images      | false                         |
| skip_upload_screenshots | false                         |
| validate_only           | false                         |
| check_superseded_tracks | false                         |
| timeout                 | 300                           |
| deactivate_on_promote   | true                          |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+

[14:09:27]: Preparing to upload for language 'en-US'...
[14:09:31]: Uploading all changes to Google Play...
[14:09:34]: Successfully finished the upload to Google Play
```

How can I use Fastlane's `supply` action to increase the roll-out percentage of the current release in the "Production" track?

**Update:**
Did not find an actual solution for the problem using Fastlane so we switched to the [gradle-play-publisher plugin](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher) by Triple-T which can do what we wanted to do.

Comment: Your output shows `track = production` while your command has `--track rollout`. Typo or real mismatch? Can you maybe update your question to include the full output you are getting (including the command you executed to get it)?

Comment: @janpio I'm using the `rollout` track, because Fastlane ignores the rollout fraction for all tracks other than the `rollout` one. See: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/3f4c596e774c8e1b756264e542fdf9d4b47c4448/supply/lib/supply/client.rb#L318

Comment: Exactly, I was wondering why your output still showed the production track. Sorry I couldn't be of more help here, but at least you found a solution. (You might want to post your update as an answer though)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my lane to update rollout percentage on production track:

```
desc "Update production rollout - Usage: fastlane rollout_prod rollout:0.25"
lane :rollout_prod do |options|
  supply(
      track: 'production',          
      rollout: options[:rollout], # 0.25
      skip_upload_apk: true,
      skip_upload_metadata: true,
      skip_upload_images: true,
      skip_upload_screenshots: true,
      skip_upload_changelogs: true,
    )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set track: rollout track_promote_to:roullout and rollout:0.5

Answer (score 0):

I make workaround for this problem. My workflow is

- upload_to_play_store with track: beta
- promote from beta to production with initial rollout percentage, let's say 0.25

```
    desc "Promote beta to production"
    lane :init_rollout_prod do
    supply(
        track: 'beta',
        track_promote_to: 'production',
        rollout: '0.25',
        skip_upload_metadata: true,
        skip_upload_images: true,
        skip_upload_screenshots: true,
        skip_upload_changelogs: true,
        skip_upload_apk: true,
        skip_upload_aab: true
      )
   end
```

- update rollout with similar lane as above, let's say 0.50

```
    desc "update rollout prod"
    lane :update_rollout_prod do
    supply(
        track: 'beta',
        track_promote_to: 'production',
        rollout: '0.50',
        skip_upload_metadata: true,
        skip_upload_images: true,
        skip_upload_screenshots: true,
        skip_upload_changelogs: true,
        skip_upload_apk: true,
        skip_upload_aab: true
      )
   end
```